# Page title display different

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, page-title

When searching the products displayed page title is different in magento2. Before login display customer login title and after login shown correct title.Please help me any one.[image]

Comment: It's a custom template?

Comment: No, this is default magento search page

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. The problem was when we use below block in any cms block or page or template file

> Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login

then above issue arise for that specific pages.

I saw that Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login class was overriding _prepareLayout() function like this:

```
/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Customer Login'));
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

So I created a custom Block in app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Block/Form/Login extending Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login and overriding _prepareLayout() function like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Form;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login as BaseLogin;

class Login extends BaseLogin
{
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And due to above code title of customer login page removed so, I have added title in app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml before body :

```
<head>
        <title>Customer Login</title> 
 </head>
```

And the issue was solved!